# JavaScript: how to generate UUID for Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know how to generate UUID/GUID for Internet Explorer?

I have code from Broofa at: http://www.broofa.com/2008/09/javascript-uuid-function/

this works fine on almost all the browsers except IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it:

```
window.Guid = function () {
    function part() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1).toUpperCase();
    };

    return {
        NewGuid: function () { return (part() + part() + "-" + part() + "-" + part() + "-" + part() + "-" + part() + part() + part()); },
        Empty: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    };
} ();
```

now you can do:

```
Guid.NewGuid();  // new uuid
Guid.Empty;      // empty uuid
```

Comment: I'm doing it like this: alert("uuid:"+_f); and it is showing as undefined!